# How to convert 2016-06-14 21:40:53 to today in php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How to convert 2016-06-14 21:40:53 as yesterday, 2016-06-15 21:40:53 as today and 2016-06-16 21:40:53 as tomorrow in php

Comment: `function convert($time){ if ($time == '2016-06-15 21:40:53' ){ return 'today'; } else { return '¯\_(ツ)_/¯';}}` - of course, you could add the other strings too.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: PHP `date` built-in function doesn't provide such format. You will need to create your own function to calculate this. There is a library called Carbon that can help speed things up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$yourDate = new DateTime('2016-06-16 21:40:53');
$yourDate->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTime(0, 0, 0);

$diff = $now->diff($yourDate);
$diffInDay = (int)$diff->format('%R%a');

if ($diffInDay == -1) {
    echo 'Yesterday';
} else if ($diffInDay == 0) {
    echo 'Today';
} else if ($diffInDay == 1) {
    echo 'Tomorrow';
} // ... etc
```

[Official documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think your looking for

```
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $newdate = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
    $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , $newdate );
     //yesterday
    echo $newdate;

    $tommorow = strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
    $tommorow = date ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' , $tommorow );
    echo $tommorow //tommorrow

    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s') //today
```